# ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.9.0 or later Error When Using Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite

I'm receiving the below error message when running this command in my Django project "python manage.py migrate"  How do you upgrade to a later version of SQLite on CentOS 7 x64bit?

```
Error:
SQLite 3.9.0 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite_version
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.9.0 or later is required (found 3.7.1                                                                   7).
```

# python -V

```
Python 3.6.8
```

# sqlite3 --version

```
3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22 118a3b35693b134d56ebd780123b7fd6f1497668
```

# uname -a

```
3.10.0-1160.25.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 28 21:49:45 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

# python3 -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"

```
3.2.9
```

# cat /etc/centos-release

```
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by using mysql with django instead.  I don't know why there wasn't an official release of sqlite 3.9.X+ that can be used on CentOS 64bit with Django, but MySQL works perfectly.